# Export values not formulas with VBA

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I am using the script below to export a worksheet as a CSV:

```
Sub Button14_Click()
  '
     ' export Macro

    Dim LR As Long
    LR = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Range("A2:M" & LR).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, 23).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Workbooks.Add
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _
    "C:\upload\19meat-kl.csv" _
    , FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    ActiveWorkbook.Close
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

I am a novice at VBA scripting and I actually got this code from another post.

For the most part it does what I want but if I try to use a formula it exports the formula rather than the result.  What do I need to change so that the cell contents are what is exported?

Comment: Just for the record, VBA isn't VBScript

Comment: Change `.Paste` for `.PasteSpecial xlValues`

Comment: I tried changing it and i am getting _Runtime error 1004 PasteSpecial method of Worksheet class failed_

Comment: That's because the copy and paste operations need to be right next to each other; adding a workbook will clear the clipboard.

Comment: Also... ditch that macro-recorder crap code and stop relying on activesheet, activeworkbook and selection. Workbooks.Add is a function that returns a workbook object, and you discard it. Your life would be much easier if you grabbed that object and worked off of it.

Answer (score 1):

Further to the comment by @Mat'sMug you need to use `PasteSpecial xlValues` and not just `Paste`.

Try this example code below - it does what your original macro does but with some best practices:

- Use `Option Explicit` to prevent issues with badly defined variables
- Set references to source data and target data e.g. source worksheet (`wsSource`), source range (`rngToCopy`), target workbook (`wbTarget`) and 
  target worksheet (`wsTarget`) - this is better than using `ActiveSheet` or `Something.Select` and so forth, which is *not* best practice
- Do the *paste* immediately after the *copy* to prevent issues with clipboard persistence

Code:

```
Option Explicit

Sub SaveRangeDataAsValuesOnNewWorkbook()

    ' set-up your variables
    Dim strFileToSave As String
    Dim wsSource As Worksheet
    Dim lngLastRow As Long
    Dim wbTarget As Workbook
    Dim wsTarget As Worksheet
    Dim rngToCopy As Range

    ' where you want to save
    strFileToSave = "C:\upload\19meat-kl.csv"
    ' get a worksheet reference
    Set wsSource = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1") '<~~ set to your worksheet
    ' get last row in column A - you need to reference a worksheet to do this properly
    lngLastRow = wsSource.Range("A" & wsSource.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    ' now - add a workbook and get its reference
    Set wbTarget = Application.Workbooks.Add
    ' get the first worksheet in the new workbook
    Set wsTarget = wbTarget.Worksheets(1)
    ' get a reference to your source range
    Set rngToCopy = wsSource.Range("A2:M" & lngLastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, 23)
    ' copy the source range
    rngToCopy.Copy
    ' paste it to the target worksheet in the new workbook - you need to PasteSpecial to a Range
    wsTarget.Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlValues
    ' save the new workbook
    wbTarget.SaveAs Filename:=strFileToSave, FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False
    ' close the new workbook
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    wbTarget.Close
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```